# Retrieving integers from list in python

Tags: python, list, pyqt4

I am trying to retrieve the list of random integers saved into the list "self.buttons". However I cannot successfully access them

```
    moveButton = 70
    self.buttons = []

    for i in range(5):
        numberLabel = random.randint(-1000,1000)
        self.buttons.append(Button(str(numberLabel), self))
        self.buttons[i].setFixedSize(160, 80)
        self.buttons[i].move(moveButton,200)
        moveButton = moveButton + 160
        self.buttons[i].show()

    print(self.buttons)
```

When I try to print the list, I get...

```
[<__main__.Frame object at 0x10b1d25f0>, <__main__.Frame object at 0x10b1d2680>, <__main__.Frame object at 0x10b1d2710>, <__main__.Frame object at 0x10b1d27a0>, <__main__.Frame object at 0x10b1d2830>]
```

Instead I want the integers to print in the list! 
Any help would be much appreciated, TIA

Comment: you have to get the text propety of the button, or build an aux list with the values, that you can print...

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
print (button.numberLabel for button in self.buttons)
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: That prints, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10a8fd730>

Comment: What is the property of the button you want to print?

Answer (score 0):

The output is right. Basically what you are doing with the print statement is that you are printing the items of the list "self.buttons" which happenes to be objects of the class Button.

You specify that you are using the PyQT4 framework, correct me if I am wrong but PyQT4 doesn't contain a class named "Button". Assuming that you used the "import ... as" option and instead of "Button" you mean "QPushButton", you will need to change the last line of your code from:

```
   for i in range(5):
        numberLabel = random.randint(-1000,1000)
        self.buttons.append(Button(str(numberLabel), self))
        self.buttons[i].setFixedSize(160, 80)
        self.buttons[i].move(moveButton,200)
        moveButton = moveButton + 160
        self.buttons[i].show()

   print(self.buttons)
```

To:

```
   for i in range(5):
        numberLabel = random.randint(-1000,1000)
        self.buttons.append(Button(str(numberLabel), self))
        self.buttons[i].setFixedSize(160, 80)
        self.buttons[i].move(moveButton,200)
        moveButton = moveButton + 160
        self.buttons[i].show()
        print(self.buttons[i].text())
```

This way you don't print the position of the object at the memory but you are printing the return value of the text() function.